# How to find the sum of this series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3n^2+2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I need to calculate the sum of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3n^2+2n}$$

Using Partial Fractions I can rewrite
$$\frac{2}{3n^2+2n} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{3}{3 n + 2}$$

Comment: Sorry is the first time that i ask inside this forum and i don't know how write markdown correctly

Comment: Hints: By partial fraction and telescope cancellation.

Comment: Can you explain me how? I lost a few hours but I can't figure out how

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Ok i have an analysis test, and I'm studying the series, on an exercise I found this series and from the initial series I managed to reduce it as in the second photo. I have to see if it converges or not and if so calculate the sum. I had already seen a possible telescopic development with cancellation but I think the results are wrong, and since I didn't know where else to ask, I asked in this forum

Comment: Note that $\frac{2}{3x^{2}+2x}=\frac{2}{x(3x+2)}$, so we try $\frac{2}{x(3x+2)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{3x+2}$,
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. In computing the sum of the infinite series, write it
as $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cdots=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{3n+2}\right)$,
then you will probably have telescope cancellation for $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{3n+2}\right)$.

Comment: I have already reduced the series in fact in this photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/snNx7.png I arrived at the ∑Nn=1(An+B3n+2). But when i develop the telescope cancellation i have for a1=1-((-3)/5 for a2=1/2-((-3)/8 and i cannot find a possible cancellation

Comment: Oh... $n$ and $3n+2$ are bad combination, so we telescope cancellation may not work so obviously.

Comment: can you give me some advice on how to solve it and maybe explain the reasoning to me?

Comment: Is there a reason to think there is a closed form? If it is an exercise, maybe it is in a chapter that gives some hint of the techniques to use? If so, maybe tell us the chapter.

Comment: the exercise is about an old exam that tells "given the series, determine if it converges or not, and if it does, determine the sum"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum can be written:

$$3\sum_n \left(\frac1{3n}-\frac1{3n+2}\right)$$

Letting $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{3n}}{3n}-\frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2}\right)$$ we get $$ \begin{align} 
f'(x)&=\frac{x^2-x^4}{1-x^3}\\&=\frac{x^2+x^3}{1+x+x^2}\\&=x-\frac12\frac{2x+1}{1+x+x^2}+\frac12\frac1{1+x+x^2}. \end{align}$$

Your value can be gotten by computing $$3\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^2+x^3}{x^2+x+1}\,dx\tag1$$

The indefinite integral will be:

$$f(x)=\frac12x^2-\frac12\log(1+x+x^2)+a\arctan(bx+c)$$ for some real $a,b,c,$ I think.

Wolfram Alpha gives $\frac16(9-9\log 3+\sqrt3\pi)$ for $(1).$

Comment: As an aside, one can write the integrand as $3x^2 (1-x^2)/(1-x^3)$. Hence under the substitution $u=x^3$ the integral becomes $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-y^{2/3}}{1-y}dy$. If we replace $2/3$ with a positive integer $n$ and expand in powers of $y$, this is recognizable as the harmonic number $H_n$. So the problem is equivalent to computing $H_{2/3}$ in closed form. (It's not clear to me that this is any easier to compute than just the integral itself, so this is more of a novelty than anything substantive.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{2}{3n^2+2n}=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac 1 n -\sum_{n=1}^{p}  \frac{3}{3 n + 2}$$ $$S_p=H_p- \left(  \psi \left(p+\frac{5}{3}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\right)$$ where appear the harmonic numbers and the digamma function.

Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_q=\log (q)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12
   q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^4}\right)$$ and the relation
$$\psi(q)=H_q-\frac{1}{q}-\gamma$$ and continuing with Taylor series for large $p$
$$S_p=\left(\gamma +\psi
  \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{2}{3 p}+\frac{5}{9
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$
For sure, the problem is to know or find that
$$\psi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)=\frac{3}{2}-\gamma +\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}$$ which gives Wolfram Alpha result
$$S_\infty=\frac{3}{2} +\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}$$